# Angular 2 How to push object if my ngFor is nested

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```
commentCreated(comment){
    this._commentService.post('v1/posts/'+ this.id+ '/comments', comment)
        .subscribe(comment => this.comments.push(comment.json()))
        console.log(comment)
}
```

this code snippets work if my ngFor is not nested like this

```
<comment-card 
  [comment]="comment"
  *ngFor="let comment of comments"
  >
</comment-card>
```

but if i need to nested my ngFor because its inside of the post object

```
<comment-card 
  [comment]="comment"
  *ngFor="let comment of post.comments"
  >
</comment-card>
```

How can i push new object if my ngFor is nested

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { PosTService, ApiService } from '../../services';
import { ShareButton, ShareProvider } from 'ng2-sharebuttons';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { CommentData } from '../../services';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';


@Component({
   templateUrl: './show.component.html',
   styleUrls: [`./show.component.scss`],
   providers: [ PosTService, ApiService]
})

export class ShowPostComponent implements OnInit{
post = [];
comments: [];
facebookButton;
twitterButton;
comment = []
id: number;
constructor(
    private _router: ActivatedRoute,
    private _postService: PosTService,
    private _commentService: Angular2TokenService ){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.urlId();
    this.getPost()
    this.facebookB();
    this.twitterB();            
}

public getPost(){
    this._postService.getPost(this.id)
    .subscribe(
    post => this.post = post,
    comments => this.comments = comments,
    )
}

public urlId(){
    this._router.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = + params['id'];
    })
}

public twitterB(){
    this.twitterButton = new ShareButton(
        ShareProvider.TWITTER,              //choose the button from ShareProvider
        "<span><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></span>", //set button template
        'twitter'                           //set button classes
    );
}

public facebookB(){
    this.facebookButton = new ShareButton(
    ShareProvider.FACEBOOK,              //choose the button from ShareProvider
        "<span><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i></span>", //set button template
        'facebook'                           //set button classes
    );
}

commentCreated(comment){
    this._commentService.post('v1/posts/'+ this.id+ '/comments', comment)
        .subscribe(comment => this.comments.push(comment.json()))
        console.log(comment)
}
```

}

my comment component

Comment: Just change `this.comments` to `this.post.comments` in your first snippet

Comment: i already try that but doesnt work and an error, property comments does not exits on typ any[]

Comment: Whats the error message? Where do you using `commentCreated`?

Comment: submit comment and push into new array that is my commentCreated

Comment: Show you full component.ts